# Select a number not present in a list

Tags: algorithm, numbers

Is there an elegant method to create a number that does **not** exist in a given list of floating point numbers?  It would be nice if this number were not close to the existing values in the array.

For example, in the list `[-1.5, 1e+38, -1e38, 1e-12]`  it might be nice to pick a number like `20` that's "far" away from the existing numbers as opposed to `0.0` which is not in the list, but very close to `1e-12`.

The only algorithm I've been able to come up with involves creating a random number and testing to see if it is not in the array.  If so, regenerate.  Is there a better deterministic approach?

Comment: do you have any constraints about the range - for example, if you were to sort the list, then generate numbers always lower than the smallest or higher than the largest - is that hole acceptable?

Comment: That's a good idea, but unfortunately, it's possible that I have both the maximum and minimum possible 32 bit float in the list.

Comment: Hmm, in that case, the sort + binary search and then a test for acceptable "distance" is about the best I can think of as well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the constraint, that the new value must be somewhere in between `[min, max]` then you could sort your values and insert the mean value of the two adjacent values with the largest absolute difference.

In your sample case `[-1e38, -1.5, 1e-12, 1e+38]` is the ordered list. As you calculate the absolute differences, you'll find the maximum difference for the values `(1e-12, 1e+38)` so you calculate the new value to be `((n[i+1] - n[i]) / 2) + n[i]` (simple mean value calculation).

**Update:**
Additionally you could also check if the `FLOAT_MAX` or `FLOAT_MIN` values will give good candidates. Simply check their distance to `min` and `max` and if the result values are larger than the maximum difference for two adjacent values, pick them.

Comment: This would work really well. The only downside I see is that all generated values will be positive..

Comment: @ramsesoriginal: I added the concrete formula. There shouldn't be a problem with the sign.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to select a *random* number not in the list, where the probability is higher the further away from an existing point you get.

1. Create a probability distribution function *f* as follows:

   *f(x) = <the absolute distance to the point closest to x>*

   such function gives a higher probability the further away from the a given point you are. (Note that it should be normalized so that the area below the function is 1.)
2. Create the primitive function *F* of *f* (i.e. the accumulated area below *f* up to a given point).
3. Generate a uniformly random number, *x*, between 0 and 1 (that's easy! :)
4. Get the final result by applying the inverse of *F* to that value: *F<sup>-1</sup>(x)*.

Here's a picture describing a situation with 1.5, 2.2 and 2.9 given as existing numbers:

[image]

**Here's the intuition of why it works:**

- The higher probability you have (the higher the blue line is) the *steeper* the red line is.
- The *steeper* the red line is, the more probable it is that *x* hits the red line at that point.
- **For example:** At the given points, the blue lines is 0, thus the red line is horizontal. If the red line is horizontal, probability that *x* hits that point is zero.

(If you want the full range of doubles, you could set min / max to -Double.MAX_VALUE and Double.MAX_VALUE respectively.)

Comment: Not only is the the correct way to do it, if you want to get the number which is maximally separated from the other numbers all you have to do is take the maximum of `f` (which is easy since it is simply a piecewise continuous set of linear functions!)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no upper bound, just sum up the absolute value of all the numbers, or subtract them all.

Another possible solution would be to get the smallest number and the greatest number in the list, and choose something outside their bounds (maybe double the greatest number).

Or probably the best way would be to compute the average, the smalelst and the biggest number, as long as the standard deviation. Then, with all this data, you know how the numbers are structured, and can choose accordingly (all clustered around a given negative value? Chosoe a positive one. All small numbers? Choose a big one. etc.)

Something along the lines of

```
    number := 1
    multiplier := random(1000)+1
    if avg>0
        number:= -number
    if min < 1 and max > 1
        multiplier:= 1 / (random(1000)+1)
    if stdDev > 1000
        number := avg+random(500)-250
        multiplier:= multiplier / (random(1000)+1)
```

(just an example from the top of my head)

Or another Possibility would be to XOR all the numbers together. Should yield a good result.